# Multiple Modal Windows

Tags: smartclient

I want to open this window on top of an existing almost full screen modal. The issue is that the modal mask doesn't cover the parent modal and the modal behind the parent is twice as dark. Is there a solution to this?

```
isc.Window.create({
    height: 100,
    width: 250,
    autoCenter: true,
    isModal: true,
    showModalMask: true,
    modalMask: this
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that setting modalMask is what you need. Try setting modalMaskOpacity instead (default is 50, and 100 means no Opacity).